# Debugging AngularJS Databinding Inline Directive vs Directive in ngTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3036/

I have two directives that are using two-way databinding on a value provided by the same controller instance.  When the directives are inlined everything works.  When the directives are embedded in a template and included using `ngInclude` the binding partially fails (see fiddle).

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code 
1) You have defined ng-controller Multiple times.Please be informed that everytime you define a ng-controller a new scope is created
2) your model test is a primitive which will cause problem during prototypical inheritance instead watch on object not primitive type directly

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

I have modified your fiddle which is working now :http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/3037/

```
 $scope.newtest={value:true}
```